# Disable outlook from storing local data

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have outlook 2007 connected to Google's account. In the moment I created the connection, Outlook started to download all my mails to my computer (to the PST file) - Is there any way to disable outlook from saving mail data locally? I just want it to save my calender and to-do data locally, and mail to function as regular web browser web app - just talking to the server.

Is it possible? if not with outlook so with some other program?

Thank you.

Comment: Active Exchange, IMAP, or POP3.  If you are using POP3 it means you have to use a data file.  The other two require a cache file.  In other words the files that Outlook creates are required for Outlook to function.  Any desktop alternative would require a local data file if its going to retrieve data.  Just keep the messages on the server and automatically delete any emails you recieve by creating filtering rule.